Geometry of the same angle around a normal on an ellipsoid
I have a question that is difficult for me to explain.
I have an ellipsoid with a polar and equatorial radius.
So radius $r \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $r_x = r_y$ and $r_x \neq r_z$.
And I define a direction vector $\overrightarrow{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.
and an angle $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.
The normalized normal direction vector $\overrightarrow{n} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ of the surface, which is equal to the normalized direction vector $\overrightarrow{v}$, is coloured red.
All normal vectors $\overrightarrow{n'} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ on the surface where $\theta > acos(\overrightarrow{n'} \centerdot \overrightarrow{n})$ are shown as a step in the image. The symbol $\centerdot$ is used as dot product.
I would like to know more about the shape of the step or sillouette where $\theta = acos(\overrightarrow{n'} \centerdot \overrightarrow{n})$.
Regardless of the value of $\theta$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$, is the shape of the step a cone or a cylinder geometry with two radii?
If so, how can we determine the position (apex), direction and radii of the cone?
I expect the direction of the cone/cylinder to be $\overrightarrow{n}$, while the position is somewhere on the red line.

